# Equation of a polygon

Tags: geometry, parametric, polygons

I need a parametric equation for a filled polygon defined by 3 or more points. The closest I've got is by using 3 points in this equation - $polygon = p1 + u(p2-p1) + v(p3-p1)$. But by using points (0,0), (2,1) and (3,1) instead of getting a triangle it makes a [parallelogram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot3D%5B%7B2u%20%2b%20v,%20u%20%2b%20v,%200%7D,%20%7Bu,%200,%201%7D,%20%7Bv,0,1%7D%5D). Is it possible to define such equation using 3 or more points and getting a filled polygon?

Comment: Are piecewise functions allowable? If so, it becomes simpler.

Comment: @N.Owad Yes, they are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that for $t\in [0,1]$, we can make a straight line from any point $p_1$ to $p_2$ by $(1-t)p_1 + tp_2$.  So, given $n$ points $p_1,\ldots,p_n$, and $t\in [0,n]$, we just rescale the straight line between each of the pairs of points.

$$f\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
(1-t)p_{1}+tp_{2}, & t\in\left[0,1\right]\\
(2-t)p_{2}+\left(t-1\right)p_{3}, & t\in\left[1,2\right]\\
(3-t)p_{3}+\left(t-2\right)p_{4}, & t\in\left[2,3\right]\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
\left(n-t\right)p_{n}+\left(t-n+1\right)p_{1} & t\in\left[n-1,n\right]
\end{cases}$$

So, for you specific example, we would have:
$$f\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
\left(0,0\right)+t\left(2,0\right), & t\in\left[0,1\right]\\
(2-t)\left(2,0\right)+\left(t-1\right)\left(2,1\right), & t\in\left[1,2\right]\\
(3-t)\left(2,1\right)+\left(t-2\right)\left(0,0\right), & t\in\left[2,3\right]
\end{cases}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't too helpful, because in this way I can get only the outline of the polygon, which is the easiest part. What I was asking was an equation for a filled polygon by using both parameters t and s.

Comment: Take a interior point $(x_0,y_0)$. $g(s,t)=sf(t)+(1-s)(x_0,y_0)$, $s\in[0,1]$, $t\in\cdots$

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla How to find the interior point?

Comment: (sum vertices)/3

Comment: You should also be careful about the ordering of the vertices, as you can form a self-intersecting polygon.